# How to correctly control translation transformation position after doubleAnimation completes in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have an **ellipse** in the **middle of a Canvas** using this code:

```
var FixedCircle = new Ellipse
{
    Width = 25,
    Height = 25,
    Stroke = color,
    Fill = color,
    StrokeThickness = 3
};
var centerX = ActualWidth / 2;
var centerY = ActualHeight / 2;
FixedCircle.Margin = new Thickness(centerX, centerY, 1, 1);
Children.Add(FixedCircle);
InvalidateVisual();
```

I want to animate the ellipse, making it **go from  left and back to center** (starting middle point).

I am setting coordinates `(centerX,centerY)` and `(0,centerY)` as starting and end points, also I am using the lines

```
Point oldPoint = FixedCircle.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(centerX,centerY));
Point newPoint = FixedCircle.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0,centerY));
```

to indicate that transform must be set to starting pointg, I tried deleting this but the movement gets worse and starts from botton, or coordinate `(0,0)` is seen as the middle instead of `(ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2)` which is something I dont want.

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
FixedCircle.RenderTransform = trans;
Point oldPoint = FixedCircle.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(centerX,centerY));
Point newPoint = FixedCircle.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0,centerY));
var EndX = FixedCircle.Width / 2 + newPoint.X - oldPoint.X - (FixedCircle.Width);
var EndY = FixedCircle.Height / 2 + newPoint.Y - oldPoint.Y - (FixedCircle.Height);
var a1X = new DoubleAnimation(0, EndX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

a1X.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    oldPoint = FixedCircle.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, centerY));
    newPoint = FixedCircle.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(centerX, centerY));
    EndX = FixedCircle.Width / 2 + newPoint.X - oldPoint.X - (FixedCircle.Width);
    EndY = FixedCircle.Height / 2 + newPoint.Y - oldPoint.Y - (FixedCircle.Height);
    var a2X = new DoubleAnimation(0, EndX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, a2X);
};
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, a1X);
```

The effect I get is ellipse **correctly go from middle to left**

[image]

then the issue of my **problem**, **it starts in the middle and go to the right**, when I need the ellipse to go from **left to middle, not middle to right**:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Without reading through all your code, one point is clear. You should not set the Ellipse's Margin. Either you animate the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties and start with appropriate initial values, or you animate a TranslateTransform, also with an appropriate initial RenderTransform.

Comment: How exactly should the Eliipse move? Is it a continuous animaton or is is supposed to be triggered multiple times to move from its current position to a new one?

Comment: would like to be a continuos animation, from middle to left, then from left to middle and so on

Comment: So, i deleted setting margin code, How would I init the ellipse at center of screen, and the procede to animate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code runs a repeated animation from middle to left and back. It uses a Path with an EllipseGeometry, because that is centered (instead of top/left aligned like an Ellipse). It also draws no stroke, but just adds the stroke thickness to the ellipse's radius.

```
var transform = new TranslateTransform(canvas.ActualWidth / 2, canvas.ActualHeight / 2);

var radius = 14;

var circle = new Path
{
    Data = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(), radius, radius),
    Fill = Brushes.White,
    RenderTransform = transform
};

canvas.Children.Add(circle);

var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    To = radius,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};

transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animation);
```

For a repeated animation from right to left and back that starts at the center point, use a negative BeginTime:

```
var transform = new TranslateTransform(
    canvas.ActualWidth - radius, canvas.ActualHeight / 2);

var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    To = radius,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-3)
};
```

Comment: what is ´To = radius,´ doing?

Comment: Still, dont get how you tell to go to left, I mean, I get the autoreverse part, but how could you change your code so ellipse moves to the right for instance?

Comment: It is the leftmost value of the X value of the circle's center. Otherwise if would half disappear at the left border.

Comment: Move to the right by `To = canvas.ActualWidth - radius`

Comment: You may also want to add an EasingFunction to the animation for a movement with variable speed.

Comment: Ok, that is very nice, I understand now, only one more question, suppose I would like to go from middle to left then from left to middle, then middle to right, and finally right to middle, is a storyboard needed  or could be done adding other animation to your code?